# Hyperlinking to a page with the same query string parameter key within a Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've got a Blazor web assembly app and a page with the route `/Documentation/ViewRecord` with a query string parameter with the key `recordtype` e.g. something like this `https://localhost:7033/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=1`.

This page also contains links to the same route with the different value for the recordtype e.g. `https://localhost:7033/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=1789`, `https://localhost:7033/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=53`, `https://localhost:7033/Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=735`...

However, when clicking on the links, the URL in the browser changes to the correct path however the page doesn't update/refresh. The page only updates if I press enter/tell the browser to go to the url.

I believe this is a known issue with Blazor WASM however is there a workaround for this?

I've added the following but that only gets hit on the initial page load; not when the links get clicked:

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the navigation manager's force load option:

```
@inject NavigationManager n

@{
  var uri = "Documentation/ViewRecord?recordtype=1789";
}

<a href=@uri
   @onclick=(() => n.NavigateTo(uri, forceLoad: true))
   @onclick:preventDefault
>
    Click me
</a>
```

Comment: But using this way you reload all the blazor SPA is very slow.

Comment: Agreed. The parameter solution is better

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue. This is just how Blazor works. When you are on `ViewRecord` with `recordtype=178` and go to `recordtype=156` it doesn't go through the "OnInitialized" method and it doesn't re-render its components.

Up to my knowledge there is no built-in way how to achieve re-render elegently.

You may re-create your app to do everything important in `OnParameterSet` instead of `OnInitialized`, but this may go deep, deep and deep.

You also may do force reload like in previous answer, but it will reload all the resources and restart the app.

I have figured out this non-elegant, but working-well solution with one time hit of periodic timer.

When the parameter changes, you "remove" all the content (with `render=false`) and in 50 ms re-render it again...:

```
@page "/ViewRecord"

@if(render)
 {
   <SomeComponent/>
   <AllOtherComponents/>
 }

@code{
[Parameter,SupplyParameterFromQuery] public string? recordtype { get; set; } 

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
  //todo: check if the recordtype has changed

  render = false;
  var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));

  if (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
  {
    render = true; 
    StateHasChanged();
    timer.Dispose();
  }
}

}
```

Comment: If any child component (`SomeComponent` / `AllOtherComponents`) needs to re-render when recordtype is changed, can't we just add a RecordType parameter to these sub-components ? Either directly or via CascadingParameters. In this way the child will re-render if and only if it is needed. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @GaëlJames `SupplyParameterFromQuery` works only on routable component (pages). If you want to send it to components like: `<SomeComponent RecordType=recordtype/>` (or with cascading param) you definitely can - it is the first solution I suggested. You will need to change logic of updating things underneath (no `OnInitialized` called in subcomponents).